# Run multiple threads until one exits in python

Tags: python, multithreading, kill

I would like to run multiple threads, each of them has the same purpose but each uses a different method. Therefore, when one of them finds the data, I no longer need the other ones and I can just kill them. I've read that it isn't good to kill threads because they might be doing something with a crucial resource. So my question is, how can I achieve this kind of thing without doing 'bad' things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Let's say we have two functions who calculate the value of Pi, `calculate1()` and `calculate2()`. In this case `calculate2()` is faster.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def calculate1(result_queue):
    print "calculate1 started"
    time.sleep(10)
    result = 3.14
    result_queue.put(result)
    print "calculate1 found the result!"

def calculate2(result_queue):
    print "calculate2 started"
    time.sleep(2)
    result = 3.14
    result_queue.put(result)
    print "calculate2 found the result!"

result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calculate1, args=[result_queue])
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calculate2, args=[result_queue])

process1.start()
process2.start()

print "Calculating the result with 2 threads."

result = result_queue.get() # waits until any of the proccess have `.put()` a result

for process in [process1, process2]: # then kill them all off
    process.terminate()

print "Got result:", result
```

This outputs:

```
calculate1 started
calculate2 started
calculate2 found the result!
Got result: 3.14
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I need, Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without queues? Because I prefer, if possible, to do that without altering the methods (adding arguments and result_queue.put...)

Comment: @pystudent I am not sure. However, you can consider making a wrapper function if you   don't want to modify your original function.

Comment: Once again, you have saved my day, Thank you!